How to reply to email from Professor
I have applied for a postdoc position in the US. I got a reply from PI asking for a Zoom call. How should i reply? I will be thankful for your response.

You asked for the position, so, presumably, you want it. Thus, you should reply with something like:

Thank you for your reply, I'd be delighted to meet with you. Can you
suggest some days and times?

If you are not in the same time zone as the university, then you might want to add your time zone.

Actually, I think asking for suggestions is annoyingly passive in this situation. Instead, offer them.

@Arno Actually, I think suggesting some times seems like you are not taking into account the potential busy schedule of the PI. It would be much better if you say something as,  "I am available for a Zoom call at your convenience. If you would be so kind as to suggest some times, I will be able to confirm quickly." If this is a position you are really interested in, you should receive a few options that work  for you, possibly by making changes to you existing schedule.

@Arno I disagree. I think asking for times is respectful and says that you are willing to adjust your schedule to match theirs.

You can do both: suggest a specific time and respectfully make clear you can accommodate their schedule. This moves the conversation along (and therefore makes more efficient use of the professor's time).

thank you all.. this was my first application for postdoc.. lets see.. what happens.. if i get selected, can i get recommendation letter from my current employer. it has been a year that i am working here in this lab.. my team lead is also phd. she can give me good reccomendation letters. but my supervisor has fluctuating emotions.. She gets provoked easily if her favourite student instigates her. also she has got multiple retractions.. and has tortured me a lot..I completed my phd work in Sept 2021 , submitted thesis in 2022, and viva in 2024.so it has been a long time since i left that place

PI are human beings, even professor that try to hide this fact are human beings (ok, with remote call you may have AI-doubts, but still the main feature of AI-impersonators is to mimic human-beings).
Are you interested in the position? then, yes, propose some time windows, good luck!
